Error Building A Game From Xcode; ExternalBuildToolExecution & Internal inconsistency error
I'm trying to build a game using Xcode 15.3 with Unreal Engine 5.3.2 and I get these errors:
Internal inconsistency error: never received target ended message for target ID '1' (in target 'Test_Build' from project 'Test (Mac)'). Build again to continue.
Command ExternalBuildToolExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
I'm on MacBook Pro M3 Max, macOS Sonoma 14.4.1.
I searched the forums but couldn't find a viable answer; any idea how to fix it?

I am having the exact same problem on Unreal Engine 4.27. Please let me know if you have found a resolution.
Thank you.
